# Convert packed data to aligned data while copying in C

Tags: c, alignment, memcpy, memory-alignment

I want to copy a set of data( each sample is 3 bytes) from a 4 byte wide packed memory to a memory that is 4 byte wide and aligned to 4 bytes.

```
Data samples: 0x345678, 0xDEFF12, 0x689ABC, 0xABCD24


Ex: Source (each 3 byte data is packed in the 4 byte  wide memory):
Add0 : 0x12345678
Add1 : 0X9ABCDEFF
Add2 : 0XABCD2468

Destination (4 bytes wide but each data is 4 byte aligned):

Add5: 0x345678
Add6: 0xDEFF12
Add7: 0x689ABC
Add8: 0xABCD24
```

What is the best way to accomplish this through memcpy?

Comment: Are they all contiguous in memory? I.e., are Add0, 1, and 2 elements in an array?

Comment: Yes, they're contiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the source and destination are arrays, the following should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  unsigned int src[] = { 0x12345678, 0X9ABCDEFF, 0XABCD2468 };
  unsigned int dest[4] = { 0 };

  typedef unsigned char BYTE;
  BYTE *pSrc = (BYTE*)(src), *pDst=(BYTE*)dest;

  for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
  {
    memcpy(pDst, pSrc, 3);
    pSrc += 3;
    pDst += 4;
  }

  for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
  {
    printf("%x\n", dest[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
345678
deff12
689abc
abcd24
```

Comment: Simple and concise. Thanks